# Where can I define the global mixins so I can use them from any another stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I created a file called mixins inside stylesheet folder in assets pipeline, so I can use the mixins inside this file from any another stylesheet, but It doesn't work and I got error `Undefined mixin 'mymixin'`.
so any help how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import this file in your application css file like this `@import "mixins.ext";`